# How do you create a custom activity in CRM 2011 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android-activity, dynamics-crm-2011

I've tried this:

```
function CreateCustomActivity(oDataPath, oDataSetName, subject, entityId, entityTypeCode) {    
    var customactivity = new Object();
    customactivity.subject = subject;
    customactivity.regardingobjectid = entityId;
    customactivity.activitytypecode = entityTypeCode;

    var jsonCustomActivity = JSON.stringify(customactivity);

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", oDataPath + "/" + oDataSetName, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.send(jsonCustomActivity);
}
```

however, I get the following error:

> Error processing request stream. The
>   property name 'subject' specified for
>   type
>   'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.new_customactivity'
>   is not valid.

The first property I add to the `customactivity` object is referenced in the error message.  I get the same message when I add `regardingobjectid` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your activity object with the following notation:

```
var customactivity = {
    Subject: subject,
    RegardingObjectId: {
        Id: entityId,
        LogicalName: entityLogicalName
    }        
};
```

Also, I'm not sure off hand but the property names may be case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It was definately a case sensitivity issue.  I was able to get it to work by creating the customactivity object both the way you demonstrated and the way I had created it originally.